# Plotting $f: x + i\,y \mapsto u + i\, v$ with Plot3D and mapping $v$ to color

Tags: functions, complex

Mathematica already has `ComplexPlot3D` that plots `ReIm[x, y]` against `Abs[f(z)]` and `Arg[f(z)]`.

But what if I wanted to plot my function using an extension of the `x,y,z` space? For example, I might have a $f(z) = z^2+1$ and want to plot $w = f(z)$, where $z = x + i y$ and $w = u + i v$, in a more traditional way where the axes are $x,y$ and $u$ and for $v$ I would use colour.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please explain exactly what you're trying to do. Is it to show two planes, one an *xy*-plane for the domain and the other a *uv*-plane for the codomain? (But then just what does "color" have to do with it?) And if so, what kind of "plot" do you want: there are various possibilities, such as plotting points in the first and their images under *f* in the second, or plotting families of curves in the first and their images under *f* in the second.

Comment: ok thats a fair question. Perhaps i should have explained. ok so if you plot 2 complex numbers z and f(z) you get 4 components re(z), img(z), re(f(z)) and img(f(z)) which means they are 4 variables. The normal way of plotting a 3d complex function in mathematica is to use img, re, abs and arg. But there is a different method where you just directly plot the graph in 4 dimensions using the 4 varibles. lets say f(z)=w and w=u+iv and z=x+iy. Which means we have a graph of x,y,u and v. but one of them needs to be the 'color' of the graph. we use color for the extra 4th dimension

Comment: then I think the answer by BlacKow does exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: > `Mathematica already has ComplexPlot3D that plots ReIm`
No, it plots Abs, Arg (also called "Mod-Arg 3d plot").
> `I want ... `
basically, You want  "Re-Im 3d plot"

Answer (score 2):

I'm probably missing something, but have you tried using `Plot3D` with `ColorFunction`?

```
f[z_] := z^2 + 1;
Plot3D[Re@f[x + I*y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue@Im@f[x + I*y]]]
```

[image]

It looks nice, but it's completely wrong, obviously if `x=0` or `y=0` the imaginary part is zero, so the color should be the same.

`ColorFunctionScaling` is messing things up as explained [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/197400/plot3d-colorfunction-depending-on-x-y-or-z?noredirect=1#comment511518_197400).

So we need to disable automatic scaling and do it manually with 0.005 factor in `ColorFunction`

```
Plot3D[Re@f[x + I*y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[0.005 Im@f[x + I*y]]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

Comment: yooo thanks so much man it works like a charm. can i just ask how i could add a bar legend that matches the colour to something. Also what does plotpoints do?